# java pass jTextfield text on jframe to seperate class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a swing jFrame set up with a control group which contains 3 radio buttons.
when one is clicked it sends its label to a jtextfield

in a different class i have code parsing text by a term

```
 Scanner s = null;

    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Stage_One.txt")));
        s.useDelimiter("\\*");
        String total = (s.next());
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\n[\\n]+");

        String[] parts = p.split(total);
        boolean searchArrayResult = false;
        java.io.File targetFile = new java.io.File("/Stage_Two.txt");
        java.io.FileWriter filew = new java.io.FileWriter(targetFile);
        java.io.PrintWriter print = new java.io.PrintWriter(filew, true);
        for (String str : parts) {
            searchArrayResult = str.contains("THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE RESULT OF THE RADIO BUTTON GROUP");
            if (searchArrayResult) {

                print.println(str + "\n");
                //System.out.println(str + "\n");
            }
        }
        while (s.hasNext()) {
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

}

I just need to know how to access the jframe variables (textfields, panels and such) so i can use their inputs in code to filter a text file. i know i have to link the 2 together but i am unsure of how to do it, and most searches are for jFrame to jFrame.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the text and pass it to the class that needs it like via a predefined method (like a setter)

Comment: @MadProgrammer some thing like this?
public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
and if so, do i have to have an import statement on the class.
sorry total newbie at this.

Comment: Yes and you will only need to import the class (that needs the value) if it does not not reside within the same package as the frame